# Charge structure of the neutron

Tags: nuclear-physics, charge, quarks, neutrons, textbook-erratum

David Griffiths’ book on elementary particles says that the neutron is positive at the center and edges, negative in between. (*Introduction to Elementary Particles*, Wiley, 1987, p. 21).

But [Wikipedia disagrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron#Structure_and_geometry_of_charge_distribution), saying the opposite, with what seems to be an unimpeachable reference: Miller, G.A., “Charge Densities of the Neutron and Proton”, *Physical Review Letters*, **99**, #11, p. 112001, [doi 10.1103/PhysRevLett.99.112001](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.99.112001).

Is this an error in Griffiths?  Or has the theory about the interior of the neutron been revised since 1987?  The Miller abstract does say that the negative-at-the-center distribution is “in contrast with many expectations”.  What is the history here?

Comment: The Miller paper is available as a PDF on JLAB's website: https://userweb.jlab.org/~punjabi/miller_tranverse_nucleon_charge_density.pdf I don't know the answer but anything from JLAB is later than 1987. The first physics papers from the lab were in the early 1990s.

Comment: Did you miss this line: *"Here we present the first phenomenological  analysis of existing data  to determine $\rho(\mathbf{b})$ for the neutron and proton. The results for the neutron contradict  the  long-standing  notion,  derived  from  both  gluon-exchange and meson-cloud models"* from the first column of the first page in the JLAB PDF.

Comment: I looked for the Miller paper online, but didn't find anything except the abstract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Griffith's 1987 book correctly states a totally reasonable hypothesis, that the neutron's core is positive.  Here's a simple model which probably goes back to Fermi: the neutron ought to spend part of its time as a virtual proton-$\pi^-$ pair, in a strong-interaction analog to the photon spending part of its time as an electron-positron pair; since the proton is heavier than the pion, you'd expect to find the positive charge concentrated near the neutron's core.

Wikipedia correctly observes that [Miller shows](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2409), using data that did not exist in 1987, that the electric and magnetic form factors required to describe scattering from nucleons at different momentum transfer don't describe a charge distribution with a positive core. The simple virtual-$\pi^-$-cloud model is **wrong**.  A better model for the neutron has a negatively-charged core and a slightly negatively-charged halo, with the charge cancelling due to a positively-charged layer in between.

The quarks that make up the neutron [carry different fractions of the neutron's momentum](http://faculty.cua.edu/sober/635/Bjorken_x.pdf).  The most likely fraction of the momentum to be carried by any particular quark is $x=\frac13$, since there are three valence quarks.  However these fractions fluctuate, as quantum-mechanical properties do.  [Apparently the data show](http://physics.aps.org/story/v22/st11) that the neutron's $d$ quarks are more likely to carry more of its momentum (large $x$) than its $u$ quarks.  The high-momentum quarks, with more relativistic energy, are more likely to be found near the neutron's center of mass; since these are more likely to be $d$ quarks, the neutron's core is negative.

Comment: Why are high-momentum quarks more likely to be found at the center of mass?  I would have thought it was the opposite.

Comment: Naïve explanation: the high-momentum quarks have more total energy $E^2=p^2+m^2$, so the center of the neutron's total mass-energy distribution is nearer to them.  I suspect the explanation by Miller and Arrington referred to in the linked article is more technical.